# Why is the axiom of union harmless?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The axiom of union says:

> Let $M$ be a set of sets. Then $\bigcup M$ exists.

The axiom of replacement says:

> Let $M$ be a set and replace every element $x\in M$ with another object $x'$. Then $\{x'\mid x\in M\}$ is a set.

Most mathematicians believe that ZFC is consistent. But I wonder if it is possible to construct a set that is as big as the set of all sets or russel set by using axiom of replacement and axiom of union again and again. Why do mathematicians blindly believe that these constructions aren't contradictory?

Is there an heuristic argument that the axiom of union and the axiom of replacement can't construct "sets that are too big to be sets" (that is "contradictory sets" or "proper classes") together?

Note: If one uses an axiom system then one eventually thinks this axiom system isn't contradictory. So my question goes to everyone who uses ZFC: Why are you sure that ZFC isn't contradictory?

Comment: I don't know much about ZFC, to be hones. Not really my field. However, I love the "blindly believe". It implies the "If I don't know why this is true, then surely nobody really knows it's true" level of thinking that is on the rise all over the world.

Comment: On my side, I'm not **sure** that ZFC isn't contradictory. By the way for such a topic, I don't know what means to be **sure**. I just think it is likely to be the case... and I live with it to do math!

Comment: What does it mean "again and again" here? A finite number of times?

Comment: Yes, it means a finite number of times

Comment: If we take $ZFC$ without axiom of infinity those two axioms may be just talking about the model of finite sets, so they cannot create (on their own)  a contradictory set.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that $\operatorname{ZFC}$ is consistent. I'm not even sure that $\operatorname{PA}$ is. However, studying a theory and pushing its boundaries might very well be the best way to either prove its inconsistency or otherwise develop a heuristic reason to believe in it. So either way, it doesn't matter. If $\operatorname{ZFC}$ is consistent, it is - in my opinion - a pleasant theory to study. If it's inconsistent, we should eventually be able to find out, pinpoint the reason for its inconsistency, alter it accordingly and try again.

Comment: You might want to include replacement in the title of your question, seeing as both are involved in your little scheme and your actual question does ask about both together

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you ask for a heuristic argument why replacement and unions do not end up with proper classes. Perhaps the following helps.

The union of finitely many sets is again finite. Likewise, if we take a finite set and replace every element by another, we get again a finite set. So we see that replacement and finite unions cannot create infinite sets from finite ones. The key here is that we only allow finite unions, because if an infinite union of finite sets can quite easily be infinite.

Likewise, taking replacements and unions over sets of sets should always give back a set, and never a proper class. Of course if one allows the union to range over a proper class (for example taking the union of all sets at once) we can get a proper class, but as long as the index over which we do the union is a set, the result should be a set again.

Edit in responce to the comment below: At the very least the above shows that the collection of finite sets satisfies the axioms of replacement and union. So if one is willing to accept the existence of finite sets, then one also accepts that these axioms are non-contradictory. But the analogy also illuminates why the proposed method of taking unions and replacements over and over again does not necessarily lead to sets that are to big. Certainly, taking more and more unions leads to bigger and bigger sets, but there is no reaso  to expect these sets to ever become "too big".

I hope this helps.

Comment: Where is your argument? "Likewise" is not a convincing argument. And why are you talking about finite sets? Can you please read my question carefully. I know that the union of finitely many finite sets yields a finite set. But again, this is not my question.

Comment: @asdfadsfasdfasdf I have added a paragraph. Of course, we can't really expect a proof of the consistency of ZF in a math.se post, so there is an upper limit at how 'convincing' an argument can be. But if you give some more details about why unions and replacements would lead to "sets that are to big to be sets", I can try to adjust my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to protect against problems that occur with "set of all sets" is to protect against situations where you get:

$$S_1=S_{n+1}\in S_{n}\in\cdots \in S_2\in S_1$$

We'll say that "M is okay" if $M$ doesn't have this problem and every one of its elements is "okay." This is an intuitive definition, not a definition in ZFC.

If $M$ is okay, we assert that (again, intuitively) $\bigcup M$ is okay.

All the elements of $\bigcup M$ are "okay" because they are elements of elements of $M$, and "okay" was defined so that these are okay.

So, can we have $\bigcup M\in S_{n}\in\cdots\in S_2\in \bigcup M$? Then $S_2$ is seen to be "not okay," too, because $S_2\in \bigcup M \in \cdots\in S_2$. But $S_2\in S\in M$ for some $S\in M$, by the "definition" of $\bigcup M$. So, since $S_2$ is not "okay," then $S$ is "not okay," and hence M is "not okay."

So the axiom of union doesn't let us create stuff that is "not okay" from stuff that is "okay."

So the intuition is that we are trying to avoid loops in the set membership relationship, because that is what has always caused us paradoxes in the past. Union does not allow us to create new loops, so it is not a problem for those kinds of inconsistencies.

The axiom of replacement seems trickier, to my mind.

Comment: Your argument isn't satisfying me. Famously, there are non-wellfounded models of ZFC because of the compactness theorem. The problem is not a situation where $S_1=S_{n+1}\in S_{n}\in\cdots \in S_2\in S_1$ but a situation where there is a set of all sets that are not members of themselves.

Comment: I'm not saying that all models of ZFC are well-founded. And yes, the problem is the loop situation. You get the problematic sets by assuming first that there is a "set of all sets." While the paradox arises by taking a subset, the problem is the "set of all sets" problem. Union doesn't *add* to the problems, but that doesn't mean that every model will actually have all sets "nice."

Comment: @asdfadsfasdfasdf If you can't have loops with the relation $\in$ then the set that are members of themself don't exist and the "set of all sets that are not members of themselves" is just the set of all set.

Comment: @asdfadsfasdfasdf: You're confusing internal and external ill-foundedness. In any case, there is *never* a set of all sets which are not members of themselves. It's true that the class of sets which are members of themselves might be non-empty, if one discards the axiom of regularity, but that's not even remotely an argument why there is a set of all sets which are not members of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with "the set of all sets" isn't the size, it's the recursion. Remember, Russell's paradox says nothing about size. It asks only "Does the set of all sets that do not contain themselves contain itself?" The only consistent answer to this question is "The set of all sets that do not contain themselves is not actually a set", and one way to make that consistent - the way ZFC goes - is to say "Any set that contains itself is not actually a set", which then implies "the set of all sets is not actually a set" (because if it were, it would contain itself). We only say it's "too big to be a set" because it happens to be, in fact, bigger than any set. And because of our definition of sets, the class of all sets that don't contain themselves happens to be the class of all sets, so it too is "too big". The gist? So long as you don't create a set that contains itself you'll be fine.

So, can your process create a set that contains itself? Well, the Axiom of Union explicitly says it needs to start with a set of sets, and your instance of Replacement (the actual Axiom Schema - it's a whole thing with first order logic - quantifies over all functions, not just $x \mapsto x'$) creates no such recursive sets. So no, you won't be making a proper class, even if you replace-cum-unite an uncountable number of times.

But wait, what was that about quantifying over all functions on sets? The actual Axiom Schema of Replacement says, using your syntax:

> Let $M$ be a set and $\varphi$ a function on the elements of $M$. Then $\varphi(M) = \{\varphi(x) \mid x \in M\}$ is a set.

$\varphi(M)$ is then called the "image" of $M$ under $\varphi$, but I digress. In any case, would it be possible to create a function that somehow creates a set that contains itself? Well... no. Functions, as defined in ZFC, *map* sets to sets, they don't create new sets. Any function you create has to use pre-existing sets. Thus, at no point can you create a function that maps a set to "the set of inputs and outputs of this function" because it does not yet exist when you define the function. And since that's the set that results from a step in your replacement-cum-union scheme, this scheme cannot create a set that contains itself.

This, by the way, is a consequence of the Axiom Schema of Specification, itself a consequence of Replacement. Or rather, it's a consequence of nerfing Comprehension into Specification specifically to avoid Russell's paradox.